# javascript - If button is click execute script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
// * Removes a specific record, and decrements all records after by 1
function removeRecord(evt) {
  let button = evt.currentTarget;
  let value = parseInt(button.value);
  let row = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  removedRecords.push(row.seqNum);
  if (recordCount == 1) {
    resetRecords(true, true);
    return;
  }
  row.remove();
  for (let i = value + 1; i <= recordCount; i++) {
    let btn = document.getElementById("removeRecordBtn" + i);
    let currRow = btn.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    // * Decrements all records after by 1:
    btn.id = "removeRecordBtn" + (i - 1);
    btn.value = i - 1;
    currRow.querySelector("#recordCount").innerHTML = i - 1;
    currRow.id = "recordRow" + (i - 1);

    let selectTkt = document
      .getElementById("tktBody")
      .querySelector(".selected")
      .querySelector("#tktNum").innerHTML; // * the selected ticket

    let selectSeqNum = document
      .getElementById("tktBody")
      .querySelector(".selected")
      .querySelector("#tktNumSeqNum").innerHTML; // * the selected ticket seqNum

    console.log(selectSeqNum);

    if (btn.clicked == true) {
      // * ---Delete Row from DB if the minus button is click on a row-----
      //  prettier-ignore
      callDB(
        "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (TICKET_NUM = '" + selectTkt + "' AND  SEQ_NUM = '" + selectSeqNum + "';)"
      );
    }
  }
  recordCount--;
}
```

```html
   <!-- * Main Record Table *-->
                    <div id="steptablecontainer">
                        <div id="steptable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
                            <table id="steptable" class="compact cell-border no-footer dataTable row-border"
                                role="grid">
                                <thead id="recordTableHead">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <!-- * Names For Each Container *-->
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 25px; max-width: 25px;"></th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 50px; background-image: none; max-width: 25px;">Record</th>
                                        <th class="componentellipsis sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Component"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Type</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 125px;">Name</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Test"
                                            style="width: 100px; max-width: 50px;">Business</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dev"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Project</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 150px; max-width: 125px;">Deployer Candidate</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 400px; max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Description
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->

                                <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display: none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
                                    <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth">
                                            <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record"
                                                value="0">
                                                <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Record intializing *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>

                                        <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
                                        <div id="container">
                                            <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
                                                <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
                                                    <option value="TP">TP</option>
                                                    <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
                                                    <option value="Package">Package</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </div>


                                        <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
                                            <p>
                                                <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
                                                <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder=""
                                                    class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
                                            </p>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name"
                                                placeholder="" style="display: none;">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
                                                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
                                                    CorporateFinancialServices
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
                                                <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
                                                <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
                                                <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
                                                <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
                                                <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
                                                <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
                                                <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck"
                                                placeholder="">
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c
                                                    21000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c
                                                    20000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c
                                                    11000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1
                                                    (wm52a/b/c
                                                    40k/41k/42k)</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Description *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
                                            <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder=""
                                                class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;"
                                                </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <!-- * Add & Remove buttons *-->
                            <div class="btn-group2">
                                <div id="addRemoveButons" class="dt-buttons" style="visibility:hidden">
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn2" title="Add new record" style="display: inline-block;">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn" title="Add new record">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordRemoveBtn" title="Remove last record" style="display: none">
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So I have a table where you can add or subtract rows depending on the button click. I want the button to delete the row from a database if the minus button is click for example. I have the button to increment itself with each additional row is added. How would I get the function to work so if a user click the minus button on row 2 the rest of script is executed. How do I have an if condition in the table using a button click?
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what the issue is. Is it that you want each minus button to delete its own row?

Comment: Correct. So when the minus button for its particular row is click it executes the script set fourth in the condition. How would I do that?

Comment: ***DO NOT WRITE SQL ON THE CLIENT SIDE......***

Comment: This is just a temp code it is not going to be interacting with the Client Side

Answer (score 0):

To execute a function when a click event is triggered add the following to attribute to the button:

```js
onclick="removeRecord(event);"
```

Nowadays, `onclick` and other event attributes are no longer used as much. `EventTarget.addEventListener()` is being used instead. However, for the issue you are having, I would say that `onclick` is a better solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Gotcha thank you for the and the tip. If you dont mind though where would I add this onclick too though? Since the minus button every time it is added where would the div attach too?

Comment: It should be added to the button tag like any other attribute.
<button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record" value="0" onclick="removeRecord(event)">

Comment: Thank you for the tip it is working as I wanted too now